# Is listening for an event on a specific element causing that event to fire on unrelated elements?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events, mouseevent

Say I listen for clicks on a button

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log("button clicked");
});
```

This now activates a click listener, and if the user clicks on my button, the click event will fire on my button and then propagate to all its parents (unless the bubbling is prevented). But what if the user clicks on a completely unrelated element? Will this cause the event to fire on that element and then propagate to all of its parents too or not? (Even though there is no interest in handling those click events)

My guess is that yes, it will, because there should be a listener for clicks on the entire window once I start listening for them on a specific element. But I am not sure.

Comment: The events should fire, but unless you code it, they won't be handled.

Comment: Does your handler *cause* the event to fire when there are interactions with other elements? I would think it does not. The event system should be running irrespective of any handlers having been added. I would be surprised if it didn't start up until someone adds a handler somewhere. But I guess I don't know for sure.

Comment: @squint, Are then all events being listened even though there are no handlers whatsoever for them? This is a huge waste of processor time given the hundreads of possible events.. Are you sure about that?

Comment: @user7307621: What are you concerned about? Are you seeing performance problems when adding a single handler? I mean I'm sure the system is very optimized, but *something* needs to happen when there's a click, right? So it depends on what you mean by *"cause the event to fire"*. Still just my own conjecture, but it would seem like it would at least need to check if there are handlers for that event. If not, nothing to do. If so, there would need to be *some* sort of check to see if the handler(s) for that event type correspond to the targeted DOM element. But exactly how they optimize this...

Comment: ...could only be known by reading source code for each browser.

Comment: I am just curious whether delegating all click and key events on the `document.body` will cause any worsening in performance... <br>Turning to the second part of your comment: the reason why I think events like click don't fire if there is no single handler for them is because in some other languages you have to "start listening for click events" otherwise you won't be able to catch them and it's a bad practice to start listening for events (like mouse events) and not being interested in handling them...

Comment: Again, this is a question of optimization. You seem concerned about wasted CPU cycles but haven't given any indication that you've actually experienced an actual performance problem. Binding everything to `document.body` is going to have its own performance overhead as a result of having to have your JS manually determine which element(s) should run which code, but that's a separate issue from how the event subsystem is coded and optimized.

Answer (score 0):

From JavaScript Essentials by O'Reilly:

> When an event happens, the browser checks to see if you've defined an
>   event handler for that event; if you have, that function is run. Once
>   the function is complete, the browser begins the event loop again.
>   This event loop continues as long as the web page is loaded.

This means that, every click method is handled by browser. However, if you there's no listener assigned, it does not go further. But at least, it knows when anything is clicked.

Comment: This means that every time a user types a key, events like `keydown, keyup, keypress` will fire and cause the browser to check whether there are any handlers for each of these events, even though there are not... What a waste of CPU time...

Comment: Yes though it may look so, Javascript generally has a non-blocking I/O concept. I can suggest you some articles about it [here](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2013/10/27/the-javascript-event-loop-explained/), [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) and [here](http://altitudelabs.com/blog/what-is-the-javascript-event-loop/)